Putting QGIS 3.34 scratch files in a ramdisk (Debian 12)
I'm new to QGIS. I used GRASS a few years ago but it looks like QGIS is a bit simpler. Anyway I was merging USGS DEMs and noticed the peak ram used was 5GBytes. "TOP" indicated about 9GBytes used by the PC in total. I have 94GBytes of ram and would like to save a little wear and tear on the SSD by putting temporary files in RAM.
Googling scratch disks yields hits on creating scratch layers which isn't my goal.  I would set up a tmpfs for normal scratch ara for QGIS.
Linux framework13 6.7.12-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.7.12-1 (2024-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Are you sure it is not using /tmp/ already? On most modern systems that is a ramdisk already I think. Where is it currently writing?

It looks like on Debian 12 that /tmp is physical based on running the df command. There is a tmpfs called /dev/shm which is where a program can request storage in ram. As a quick check I can see if it grows when qgis is run.  There is also a program that monitors when files are opened.

You can use the setting Override temporary output folder path in the Processing Options (Settings -> Options -> Processing): https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing/configuration.html#general
